# Outer two groups in SES fin. gen. $\implies$ middle group fin. gen.?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a short exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ with the outer two groups finitely generated, is the middle on also finitely generated?

Of course, by the structure theorem, the answer is yes if it splits but I am not sure about the general situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $f$ be the homomorphism $A \rightarrow B$ of the sequence, and let $A=<a_1, .., a_n>$.
We have $B/f(A) \cong C$, so $B/f(A)$ is also finitely generated, say $B/f(A) = < \overline{\alpha_1}, .., \overline{\alpha_n}>$, with $\alpha_i \in B$. Then I claim $B=< \alpha_1, .., \alpha_n, f(a_1), .., f(a_n)>$. This can be seen as follows.

Let $b \in B$. Then $\overline{b} \in < \overline{\alpha_1}, ..., \overline{\alpha_n}>$, so , by definition of the quotient group, there is some $y \in < \alpha_1, .., \alpha_n>$  such that $b = yf(a)$, where $f(a) \in A$. Because $a \in <a_1, .., a_n>$, $f(a) \in < f(a_1), .., f(a_n)>$(here we use $f$ is a homomorphism). From this it follows $b \in <\alpha_1, .., \alpha_n, f(a_1), .., f(a_n)>$.